# What is the gksudo "lock taken...exiting" warning and how do I resolve it?

Tags: lock, gksu

I recently run into problems when using `gksudo`. For example, the Truecrypt installation fails because of following error:

```
** (gksudo:3262): WARNING **: Lock taken by pid: -1. Exiting.
```

PID must be a process id, but -1 can't be, correct?
How to remove this kind of lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the lock for gksudo to work.

But instead of removing it, you can just rename it to something else.

Just try the following:

```
sudo mv  ~/.gksu.lock ~/.gksu.lock.old
```

Comment: What is the advantage of renaming *a lock file* rather than removing it?

Comment: If you rename it you can restore it... No other reasons. Feel free to remove it!

Comment: It's a lock file, and these are typically blank files. So can't it just be restored by making a new one? (Furthermore, anything that uses lock files will automatically recreate them as necessary. Lock files are not about storing data in the file. They are about storing data in the state associated with the file being accessed.)

Comment: I agree I can be safely removed. This answer was helpful since I'm familiar with `mv` and just needed to know where the file is located.